# How to automatically add WFS layers in web map

Tags: html, leaflet, geoserver

I am a beginner to web map development using leaflet.
I am able to add wfs layers from the geo-server  to the web map. I am using  leaflet to style the wfs layers.
In my html I have few layers using geojson format and one WFS layer from geoserver.

My question is, whenever I add a new layer to the geoserver I want to view in my web map without updating the html.
Is there any option or method to update the html file automatically whenever I add a new layer to the geoserver?.

Thank you very much in advance for your response.

Ra

Answer (score 0):

Why not prepare an ajax call to your server that lists the available WFS layers, then direct leaflet from there?

Answer (score 0):

LayerGroups in GeoServer are probably what you are looking for.  Its still an added step to add a newly published layer to the layer group.  It does keep you from having to edit the HTML file with each new layer.

Some instructions on how to create one and the benefits are [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html)

Comment: the link is broken. it would have been nice to include some of the code/instruction here to at least give a clue.

Comment: @Niklas: Relinked to Geoserver documentation.